# Search engine indexed pages and redirection to home page

Tags: .htaccess, search-engine

I have a multidomain website running for over 12 years. Over this period, search engines have indexed tens of thousands of pages of the website. I would like to shutdown the website, and redirect the indexed pages to a temporary home page.

The questions I have are:

1. How do I find out the full list of the URLs indexed by the major search engines such as Google, Bing and Yahoo?
2. How do I easily redirect those indexed pages to the home page?

Thanks for help.

Ash